# Making part of HTML link conditional on if statement

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Picked up PHP for the first time today because an assoicate quit.

I have a link that I want to be dynamic via PHP:

```
<a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>category/recent-news/">View All News</a>
```

This section is what I want dynamic: `category/recent-news/">View All News</a>`

This is the logic I want to use:

```
<?php
$category = get_the_category();

if ($category[0]->cat_name == 'Blog')
    {
    category/blog/">View All Blog Posts</a>
    }
  else
    {
    category/recent-news/">View All News</a>
    }

?>
```

However when I input this it breaks the page. How do add the following HTML conditionally in a way that works?

Comment: Sidenote: You need to echo the `category/blog/">View All Blog Posts</a>` etc. inside your conditional statements. As it stands, the errors are to be expected. Pseudo-code? Ah, knew it ;-)

Comment: Either exit PHP with `?>` or `echo` as Fred-ii- pointed out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
    switch($category[0]->cat_name) {
       case 'Blog':
           $link = array('url' => 'category/blog/', 'name' => 'View All Blog Posts');
       break;
       default:
           $link = array('url' => 'category/recent-news/', 'name' => 'View All News');
       break;
    }
    echo '<a href="'.bloginfo('url').$link['url'].'">'.$link['name'].'</a>' 
?>
```

Comment: +1 I would go so far as to put the entire link in each conditional, if only for readability's sake.

Comment: Ye thats what i wanted. Edited :)